# Install addon to brand new profile

Tags: firefox-addon

Does anyone have any ideas on how to pre-install an addon to a brand new profile which hasn't been launched yet?

Originally, for last year, I had when people clicked on "Create New Profile" it created then launched right away with file url to the addon path, so it would prompt them if they wanted to install. But people requested I change it to not launch right away. So now I wanted to pre-install the addon (of course on startup it will find new addon and prompt permission)

Answer (score 1):

They can be pre-installed by just putting them into a new "extensions" folder inside the profile but this leaves them in a disabled state and never prompts for permission so that's probably not what you want.

Maybe there is a way to launch the profile once in the background and then put the addon into the extensions folder ready for the user to respond to the permissions prompt on the 2nd launch (although it would appear to be the first launch for them). I'm not sure if Firefox can be launched in this way but it might be worth investigating if no-one knows a way to do it into an empty profile.

Comment: Thanks lucky. Yeah I need them to get permission prompt somehow :( I filed this on bugzilla a few months ago no reply yet there :( https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694267#c8